# Merge JMeter csv results and plot a graph

Tags: jmeter

I executed load tests using Jmeter for 2 different scenarios and I have the Simple data writer output CSV files for the same. How do I merge these 2 results to see how the performance varies from one scenario to another?
I downloaded MergeResults plugin - upon adding the input files and clicking Merge, the output merged csv file gets created but there is no graphical representation which can aid comparing the results. Please can someone help?

I checked the instructions given in the [link](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) but I dont know what I am missing in order to plot the graph using the merged csv file.

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge Results generates a CSV file, if you want to see the graphical representation (chart) you need to open the file in the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice.

Alternatively if you need to generate a chart in form of a PNG image you need to use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/)  like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-png responsetimes.png --input-jtl your_merged_file.csv --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do comparison of the JMete test results easily with https://sense.blazemeter.com

1. Sign in to https://sense.blazemeter.com and create project
2. Upload the CSV files
3. Select a file
4. Click on Add to compare button at the bottom
5. Select the second file and click compare button

You can compare the test results in tabular form and in graphs.

Note : It is possible to compare multiple test result files

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my corporate proxy & policy does not allow me to upload files